# VBA FileCopy inside a loop fails after one successful copy; Problem: How to Close files before next use?

Tags: vba, filesystemobject, filecopy

**..................................................................................................................................................................**
Late-breaking news...
P.P.S. **I just read that** **`FileSystem.FileCopy`** **is better** than just `FileCopy`. That's what I'm going to try. But I **really would like to know how to use `FileCopy` inside a loop**, meaning, **"How do I close files used in `FileCopy`?"** For the big picture made clear, read on.
**..................................................................................................................................................................**

*(Using Windows 10 Pro, Word 365 Pro)*

The online Help for `FileCopy Src, Dest` says that it ... Copies a file from `Src` to `Dest` [but] does not work on a currently open file. Both ... files must be closed [by] the `Close` statement.

But the online help for `Close`, from link supplied on [that page](https://www.citect.aveva.com/webhelp/vijeo740/Subsystems/VBAVijeoWeb/content/FileCopya.html) connects to [help for Close for the Open statement](https://www.citect.aveva.com/webhelp/vijeo740/Subsystems/VBAVijeoWeb/content/Close.html), which says that it "Closes the file(s) previously opened with the" `Open` statement, not the `FileCopy` statement.

So it is that I'm stumped on what to do with this code, which will copy the *first* code module in the Document to a backup location, but *not the second*.

Pic#1: Info about what's supposedly going to be copied

[image]

Pic#2: Original error message without `On Error`

[image]

*(I have no clue why all these blank lines. They're NOT in my Body.)*

*Please ignore all the* `OnError` *stuff for now*.

When the second code module should have been copied, execution halted with error "File not found".

```
Sub BackupModules()
    Dim prj As VBProject
    Dim comp As VBComponent
    Dim code As CodeModule
    Set prj = ThisDocument.VBProject
    Dim k As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim Destination As String, Prefix As String
    Prefix = "junk"
    k = 0: n = 0
On Error GoTo x
    For Each comp In prj.VBComponents
On Error GoTo x
        k = k + 1
        If comp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
          n = n + 1
          Destination = Prefix & n
          MsgBox "Copying Standard module " & n & " of " & k & " components encountered: <" & comp.Name & "> to " _
                 & Destination & "; # lines: " & comp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
On Error GoTo x
          FileCopy comp.Name, Destination
          MsgBox "Success"
          Close
        Else

x: If Err.Number <> 0 Then: _
msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
& Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description: _
MsgBox msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext: On Error GoTo 0: Close:

       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Then I began experimenting (a LOT as you can see) with `On Error Goto x` being placed at various places (one at a time and then all, as shown) and the nasty-looking but syntactically and logically correct line that starts `x: If Err...` placed inside the `Else` block.

Pic#3: Error msg after using `On Error`

[image]

(FWIW, I just spotted `Normal` in the `Err.Source` part of the error message above. Online help says, "When an unexpected error occurs in your code, the Source property is automatically filled in. For errors in a standard module, Source contains the **project name**. For errors in a class module, Source contains a name with the project.class form." Indeed, the code is in a Module within the Normal Project.)

Pic#4: Line causing error that `On Error` did NOT trap   [image]

So **what's wrong**? I've tried everything I can think of. The only help I could find for `Close` did NOT mention its use with `FileCopy`. My `Close` usages caused no error but did `Close` close both the source and the destination file? Surely not. First use of `FileCopy` worked, files (probably) not closed, thus second use of `FileCopy` failed. Docs say using `FileCopy` on an open file will cause error.

`On Error Goto x` or to `0` is neither here nor there. That's why I said to ignore them at first.

The question is apparently "**How do I close both files** mentioned in `FileCopy`?"

P.S. ***Per opening blurb, I'm NOT gonna do this.***
I suppose I could use `Open ... For Input As File#1` and specify the Module's name, if it's readily available to code, and also `Open ... For Output As File#2` for the destination, use a `For` loop to copy the number of lines, if available, and then `Close` both. But I hope I get a solution to my problem before I try that since SURELY `FileCopy` should work within a loop (and doesn't because of improper close).

Comment: A code module is not a file, so it's unclear how you expect to use FileCopy here?  Did you mean to first export the code module to a file (in which case you could just export it to the final location)?  https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=14146

Comment: @TimWilliams--Ah. Yes. `Module <> File`. Didn't know about `Export`. I'll give that sufficient thought to expect it to help. The Link uses it but no clue how it would `Export` modules in `Normal.dotm`. It shows two folders that contain no templates, so I backed up the tree and chose the `Templates` folder that contains `Normal.dotm`, which contains the modules that I need to back up. It found ONE `VBComponent`--`ThisDocument`--and Exported it to the `Templates` folder, but no Modules were copied. The one output file, `ThisDocument.txt` is useless. I guess you've used the link. How do I use it?

Comment: @TimWilliams--Geez. THANKS for the tip about `Export`. I hadn't used File System Object before and overlooked `Export` while looking carelessly around. REALLY simplified matters.

Comment: @TimWilliams---- HEY -- Submit your `Export` comment as an Answer and I'll make it THE Answer.

Comment: No need for me to post - you can accept your own answer

Comment: NAW! YOU the MAN, not me! ... Oh, but with 102K++ rep... I gotcha...  ;^}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TimWilliams, who tipped me off to `Export`, my final "Backup all modules" routine is quite simple.

```
Sub BackupModules()
    Dim comp As VBComponent
    Dim prj As VBProject:     Set prj = ThisDocument.VBProject
    Dim fso As Object:        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim destPrefix As String: destPrefix = "C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\Word\Modules\"
    Dim destFilePath As String

    For Each comp In prj.VBComponents
        If comp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
            destFilePath = destPrefix & comp.Name & " " & Year(Now) & " " & Month(Now) & " " & Day(Now)
            Debug.Print "Copying Standard module <" & comp.Name & "> to <" & destFilePath & ">"
            comp.Export (destFilePath)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Skipping component # " & k & ", <" & comp.Name & ">, type " & comp.Type
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```